# Sudoku with chess queen rules

Tags: logical-deduction, chess, grid-deduction, sudoku

This is a unique sudoku. With Rules :

- Common sudoku rules apply.
- Numbers 1,2,3 have an additional rule, they are also chess queens.
- If all others numbers removed, the 1s do not attack each other horizontally, vertically or diagonally.
- Same rules as number 1 also apply to numbers 2 and 3.
- There is only 1 unique solution.

[image]

Comment: @JaapScherphuis : a bit typo, but not fatal. I will soon replace the image soon.

Comment: I have solved this suduko it has more than one solution will you explain the rules of chess to the suduko a little bit more

Comment: Nice innovation. Good puzzle

Comment: @rudra really? I want to see your answer. I have checked it by using computer, it only have 1 solution. Maybe I make mistake in my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my answer:

> 721  839  456
> 864  512  937
> 359  467  812
>
> 612  958  743
> 497  326  581
> 538  741  629
>
> 176  284  395
> 283  695  174
> 945  173  268

I sure hope I didn't make any silly mistakes like [last time](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57453/42572)...

The way I solved it:

> I managed to first place all threes. From there, I could place all the ones. Adding the middle left 9, central 6 and top right 5 using sudoku rules, I could place all twos. Then, all that was left was a regular sudoku.